# how to effectively dispatch an initial action in a react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reactive-programming

I have this code on my app.

```
componentWillMount() {
  if(!this.props.posts.request.sending && this.props.posts.items.length == 0) {
    this.props.fetchData({
      page: this.props.posts.request.page
    });
  }
}
```

so what the code does is when the component will be mounted, it would check to see if the props.posts is not sending any request and that there is nothing inside the items array. If so then it would dispatch an action called the `fetchData`.

My question is that, is there a better way of doing this that does not require react to handle it? because I only want react to handle the UI/UX side of things like displaying the data and dispatching an action when a button is clicked and any side effects like dispatching the initial fetch action completely separated from react.

**EDIT[1]:**

I am using redux-saga to handle all my side effects and I realized that I could do something like this:

```
const request = yield select(getRequest);
const posts = yield select(getPosts);

if(!request.sending && posts.length == 0) {
  yield fork(fetchDataWorker, { payload: { page: request.page } });
}
```

and it works perfectly fine, but is this okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the best solution that I came up with, I hope this helps someone out there. If you have a better one please feel free to post your answer.

```
const request = yield select(getRequest);
const posts = yield select(getPosts);

if(!request.sending && posts.length == 0) {
  yield fork(fetchDataWorker, { payload: { page: request.page } });
}
```

so basically you need two [selectors](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#selectselector-args), then you need to get the part of the state that you need to verify in order to run something when a certain condition was met, so in my case when the request (that came from getRequest selector) is not currently sending the request and that the posts (that came from getPosts selector) is empty then I would fork the `fetchDataWorker`, the worker is responsible for sending the API request and dispatching actions accordingly.

**getRequest selector**

```
export default function getRequest(state) {
  return {
    ...state.posts.request
  }
}
```

**getPosts selector**

```
export default function getPosts(state) {
  return [...state.posts.items];
}
```

**fetchDataWorker**

```
function* fetchDataWorker(action) {
  try {
    let response = yield call(axios.get, '/posts/' + action.payload.page);
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS', items: [...response.data.items] });
  } catch(err) {
    yield put({ type: 'FETCH_DATA_FAILED', timeOut: 5 });
    yield put({ type: 'TIMER_COUNT' });
  }
}
```